# vimのバッファの切替

Tags: vim

vimでバッファを使っていますが、1の次が3で開かれてしまいます。
また、バッファの切替のために
`nmap <C-j> <C-^>`
とマッピングしていますが、3つ以上開いているとき押しても特定の2つを行き来するだけとなってしまいます。

思うにNerdTreeのプラグインを使っているのが原因でないかと思うのですがよくわかりません。
（vimrcで起動時に開くようにしています。）

対処方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-^>` は、代替バッファ(簡単に言うと、直前にいたバッファ)を開くコマンドなので、2 つを行き来するだけなのは正しい挙動です。順番にアクセスしたい場合は `:bnext` を使ってみてください。

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> :<C-u>bnext<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

現在のバッファがどうなっているかは`:buffers`とか`:ls`で確認できます。
例えば以下のようになっていたとして、`:b4`とすると.screenrcのバッファが選択されます。

```
1  h   "~/.bashrc" 行 40
2  h   "~/.xprofile" 行 1
4 %a   "~/.screenrc" 行 290
6 #h   "~/.config/vim/vimrc" 行 406
```

私は以下のようなマッピングを使っています。
ちなみに最後を<Space>としているのは半角空白だとうっかり削除してしまうからです。

```
nnoremap <Leader>ls :<C-u>ls<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

参考文献)
[How to move around buffers in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902724/how-to-move-around-buffers-in-vim)